# SharePoint Online Restrictions Confirmation

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

Would anyone be able to confirm what the restrictions are for SharePoint Online as it seems to be ever changing. Is there a page anywhere which I can refer to as I have seen mixed reports.

[File Upload Size once was 10gb but now appears to be 15gb?](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sharepoint-online-limits-8f34ff47-b749-408b-abc0-b605e1f6d498?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

[Invalid file names and file types in OneDrive, OneDrive for Business, and SharePoint](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/invalid-file-names-and-file-types-in-onedrive-onedrive-for-business-and-sharepoint-64883a5d-228e-48f5-b3d2-eb39e07630fa)

This still seems valid " * : < > ? / \ |
But you can create a folder with ~ at the start in the UI
I can create all of the folders listed under Invalid file or folder names

Any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated. Is there a page I can take as the definitive resource for this?

Also, you can create a folder via CSOM with a . at the start ie .Folder. But in the UI you can't.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Per my test in my SharePoint online, I also can create the folder start with “.” By CSOM but I cannot create the folder start with “.” By UI.

I suggest you could open a support ticket in the Admin Center like the picture below.
[image]

More references:

How To Create New Service Request On Office 365 Support For Business Support.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-create-new-service-request-on-
office-365-support-for-business-support/

Contact support for business products - Admin Help.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/contact-support-for-business-products-admin-help-32a17ca7-6fa0-4870-8a8d-e25ba4ccfd4b